# Where are the entries of the 2nd monitor panel stored

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have an external monitor on my laptop, with multi screen setup. Often I put custom application launchers on the external monitor panel, only then to need them, when the monitor is not connected. Where can I find them?

Comment: What do you mean by commands?

Comment: Sorry I meant custom application launchers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found it.

(I had a complicated meld command on my 2nd desktop and couldn't easily find it when on the road)

A list of launchers on the panels are found under:

```
~/.gconf/apps/panel/objects/
```

I found an entry with grep:

```
<entry name="launcher_location" mtime="1312612280" schema="/schemas/apps/panel/objects/launcher_location" type="string">
    <stringvalue>meld.desktop</stringvalue>
</entry>
```

Then, you can find the command under:

```
~/.gnome2/panel2.d/default/launchers/meld.desktop
```

Comment: Please do accept your answer by clicking on the tick-mark next to your post :) It will benefit a whole lot of people that way :D